# Scrapy selector returns entire xpath rather than value

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape:
https://www.jny.com/products/cuff-sleeve-v-neck-top-floral-spice-combo

I am trying to scrape price value mentioned with the product using:

```
 price=(response.xpath('//span[@class="product-price--regular "]/text()').get)
 print("price"+str(price))
```

This returns the entire path rather than the value inside:

```
price<bound method SelectorList.get of [<Selector xpath='//span[@class="product-price--regular "]/text()' data='$69.50'>, <Selector xpath='//span[@class="product-price--regular "]/text()' data='$69.50'>]>
```

I just want the numeric value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
(Pdb) response.xpath('//span[@class="product-price--regular "]/text()').get()
'$59.50'
```

Comment: It worked. But what's the difference between mine and yours

Comment: Got it! missed the parenthesis

Comment: call `get()` this way.also, avoid redundant parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

call **get()** instead of printing the function itself.

Comment: no, you a are not calling get. that bracket after get isn't of the function call.